# Bootstrap responsive table

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a non responsive table to responsive by using bootstrap in Joomla. The table is generated by PHP for diplaying events.

I already apply bootstrap classes table and container. But the output is not responsive.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/RAnders00/5180f48307d6dad284a5) is the code that I am currently using (Take a look at line [808](https://gist.github.com/RAnders00/5180f48307d6dad284a5#file-php_file-php-L808)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this and solved.

table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr
        {display: inline-block;}

Comment: this my friend called `bootstrap table structure html tags``and if you look into the comments of my answer you see i suggested you to follow it, anyway glads it resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

remove `<div class="container">` before the table on line 808

and replace `<table class="table">` with `<table class="table table-responsive">`

Comment: You should follow the bootstrap table structure html tags also i see u r using th class not defined by bootstrap

Comment: Also did u apply media queries too? Without bootstrap media queries u will not get responsive table

Comment: Media query is present in the template's index file

Comment: is the table css also defined in media queries in template's index file

Comment: Joomla index file already have bootstrap media queries and bootstrap files loaded. should I add anything else?

Comment: I added values for this in CSS still not working
    @  media (max-width: 1050px) 
   @  media (max-width: 768px)